# Notification message tray?

Tags: fluxbox

Cinnamon desktop environment has a rather nifty idea of a tray in the systray that holds all notification messages till their read and cleared, and then becomes empty. How can I have the same thing in fluxbox please? I think it needs to be done via a bash script but I haven't the faintest idea where to start! This would be used on a debian testing machine under fluxbox desktop environment, but would hopefully be usable under ones like razor-qt as well.

Comment: I don't think it can be done with bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cinnamon desktop environment, but replace their windowmanager with fluxbox. And disable the fluxbox toolbar.